# Can I do a "string contains X" with a percentage accuracy in python?

Tags: python, string, comparison, ocr

I need to do some OCR on a large chunk of text and check if it contains a certain string but due to the inaccuracy of the OCR I need it to check if it contains something like a ~85% match for the string.

For example I may OCR a chunk of text to make sure it doesn't contain `no information available` but the OCR might see `n0 inf0rmation available` or misinterpret an number of characters.

Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As posted by `gauden`, `SequenceMatcher` in `difflib` is an easy way to go. Using `ratio()`, returns a value between `0` and `1` corresponding to the similarity between the two strings, from the docs:

> Where T is the total number of elements in both sequences, and M is
>   the number of matches, this is 2.0*M / T. Note that this is 1.0 if the
>   sequences are identical, and 0.0 if they have nothing in common.

example:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,'no information available','n0 inf0rmation available').ratio()
0.91666666666666663
```

There is also `get_close_matches`, which might be useful to you, you can specify a distance cutoff and it'll return all matches within that distance from a list:

```
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('unicorn', ['unicycle', 'uncorn', 'corny', 
                              'house'], cutoff=0.8)
['uncorn']
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('unicorn', ['unicycle'  'uncorn', 'corny',
                              'house'], cutoff=0.5)
['uncorn', 'corny', 'unicycle']
```

**Update: to find a partial sub-sequence match**

To find close matches to a three word sequence, I would split the text into words, then group them into three word sequences, then apply `difflib.get_close_matches`, like this:

```
import difflib
text = "Here is the text we are trying to match across to find the three word
        sequence n0 inf0rmation available I wonder if we will find it?"    
words = text.split()
three = [' '.join([i,j,k]) for i,j,k in zip(words, words[1:], words[2:])]
print difflib.get_close_matches('no information available', three, cutoff=0.9)
#Oyutput:
['n0 inf0rmation available']
```

Comment: like I asked gauden can this be used to check for a sub-string match though? i need to find "no info available" in what could be a page full of text

Comment: @Jacxel - I see, to do that I'd probably try cycling through 3 word matches, across the text (1st split text into words then group every chunk of three words together and try the above `get_close_matches`. Then go back to the split list and group again, but moving the index one word along, and repeat.. etc..)

Comment: @Jacxel - Updated to find a subsequence in the text

Comment: is this not very dependent on correct spacing? for example what if my text was `something no information availableandsomelongword` due to the ocr missing the space after the word available, i would get no match correct?

Comment: @Jacxel - It'll find those matches no probs, just change the `cutoff` parameter to a lower value. If the ocr can't reliably get the spacing right, and its a big issue (I doubt it'll turn out to be..), then you could join the text with no spaces into say 25 length overlapping strings (in a similar way to how i've done it with words above), and use `get_close_matches` on that. Really I think you just need to try a few things out and set `cutoff` appropriately though :)

Answer (score 6):

The [`SequenceMatcher` object](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) in the `difflib` standard library module will give you a ratio directly:

Comment: can this be used to check for a substring match? I have no means of splitting up the string in am checking and it could be 100+ characters

Comment: Hat tip and +1 to @fraxel who has got this well in hand.

Answer (score 4):

You could compute the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Here is one Python implementation: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: I thought about levenshtein distances but in my case its unlikely to to a spelling error more the odd misinterpreted character so it seems like it might be doing a lot more work than necessary

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any available python lib that would do that out of the box, but you might find one (or find a C or C++ lib and write a Python wrapper for it).

You can also try to roll your own solution, based either on a "brute force" char by char comparison, with rules defining "proximity" between two given chars and computing the "accuracy" based on these rules (ie "o" => "0" : 90% accuracy, "o" => "w" : 1% accuracy, etc), or playing with more involved IA stuff (if you're not familiar with IA, the "Programming Collective Intelligence" book could get you started, despite the somewhat poor implementation examples).

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on fraxel's answer, this allows the finding of any arbitrary length string. Sorry for the poor formatting, SO is hard. The accuracy is the cutoff value in findWords

```
def joinAllInTupleList(toupe):
#joinAllInTuple( [("hello", "world"),("face","book")]) = ['hello world', 'face book']
result=[]
for i in toupe:
    #i is the tuple itself
    carry = " "
    for z in i:
        #z is an element of i
        carry+=" "+z

    result.append(carry.strip())
return result

def findWords(text,wordSequence):

#setup
words = text.split(" ")

#get a list of subLists based on the length of wordSequence
#i.e. get all wordSequence length sub-sequences in text!

result=[]
numberOfWordsInSequence = len(wordSequence.strip().split(" ")) 
for i in range(numberOfWordsInSequence):
    result.append(words[i:])

# print 'result',result
c=zip(*result)

# print 'c',c
#join each tuple to a string
joined = joinAllInTupleList(c)

return difflib.get_close_matches(wordSequence, joined, cutoff=0.72389)
```